# Not able to download metadata for application in force.com IDE

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I am facing a few problems when trying  to integrate the force.com ide with salesforce.com.

Currently i am using eclipse(4.22 Juno) and have installed the plugin Force.com IDE(2.9) and have a developers version in salesforce.com. I was able to successfully connect to salesforce without any errors thru force.com ide, by creating a new application with the name of the application that i have created in the web version.
Right now the application is created with the sub folders classes, triggers etc... but they are empty. I also tried setting the proxy in the connections of eclipse. But even that does not seem to work.
Does anybody have any idea what could be wrong.

Thanks--

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the content of your `package.xml` file? It's kind of project definition, it contains info which files (objects, classes, pages, reports, profiles...) you want to download & push changes to.

Check http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Metadata for example - have you skipped step similar to this?

[image]

Comment: This is the package.xml       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>29.0</version>
</Package>

Comment: I had not skipped the above mentioned step. But there was one prob... I dont think i was able to view the apex classes and that is shown in your screenshot.